# Android : Smart cast to 'Bitmap!' is impossible, because 'bitmap' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

While migrating application with targetSDK 28 to 29, Android studio(3.6.2) started giving error while compiling code. With target SDK set to 28, code was compiling fine. Does anyone have idea on this?? is there any strict rule applied to this behaviour change with same android studio and Kotlin version?

Below is the code:

```
private fun generateInternalCanvas(w: Int, h: Int) {
    bitmap?.recycle()
    if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        bitmap?.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        internalCanvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    }
}
```

I am getting above error when i am assigning value to internalCanvass.

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: I think 'bitmp' is a variable ,you defined in your app. Show you code!

Comment: i have pasted the code. I can fix this with bitmap?.let { internalCanvas = Canvas(it) } but i want to know why android studio is throwing error after targetSDKVersion change? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `bitmap` is variable with null safety (the code looks like this `var bitmap : Bitmap? = null`). But i think your code is safe to make a `bitmap` to be non null in that code because you assign the bitmap with `Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)`. So the solution is you can change your code to :

```
private fun generateInternalCanvas(w: Int, h: Int) {
    bitmap?.recycle()
    if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        bitmap?.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        internalCanvas = Canvas(bitmap!!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be changed to this code:

```
private fun generateInternalCanvas(w: Int, h: Int) {
    bitmap?.recycle()
    if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) // <-
        this.bitmap = bitmap // <-
        bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        internalCanvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    }
}
```

Now you ensure this bitmap exists across the next 3 lines

Comment: Thanks for reply. I get this and there are several ways to fix. I am interested in knowing that why with targetSDK 28 code compiles fine but with targetSDKVersion 29, it started giving me compile time error. What changed internally? Any idea?

Comment: Nullability annotations for `Canvas(bitmap)`, I presume.